# Scroll to load data. Swift. UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, reloaddata

my code has some problems of loading data by scroll table to a certain row, but I couldn't find out why.

Basically, I want the table to load next 10 elements when scroll to total elements - 5. For example, I want the table initially load 10 elements. Then, when it hits the fifth element, it loads 11-20 elements.

My problem is when I initially load the table, it only loads the first 5 elements but I can see there are some spaces between 6-10, then I scroll the table to the fifth element, it loads the next 10 elements (6 - 15).

```
let rowPerPage = 10

func refreshResults(){
    // append data from server //
    self.resultsTitleArray.append(...)

    if self.resultsTitleArray.count != 0 {
        let minCount = min(rowPerPage, self.productImageArray.count) - 1
        self.currentResultsTitleArray += self.resultsTitleArray[0...minCount]
    }

    self.resultsTable.reloadData()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return currentResultsTitleArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let diff = rowPerPage - 5
    let currentDiff = currentResultsTitleArray.count - 1 - indexPath.row
    if currentResultsTitleArray.count != resultsTitleArray.count && diff == currentDiff {
        let minCount = min(resultsTitleArray.count, currentResultsTitleArray.count + rowPerPage as Int) - 1
        let next = self.currentResultsTitleArray.count
        self.currentResultsTitleArray += self.resultsTitleArray[next...minCount]
        resultsTable.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I'd change this `if` statement slightly.. What you're looking to do is load 10 cells when you're 5 away from the bottom only.. but it's slightly dangerous as it could easily load multiple times.

You need an external `var` to show the highest successful load you've done so far and check

`if indexPath.row == currentResultsTitleArray.count - 6 && indexPath.row > self.highestIndexFetchedOn` should be the trigger, then on a successful fetch, just before reload data, set `self.highestIndexFetchedOn` to the new `indexPath.row`

It's not clear what `rowPerPage` does but I'm guessing it's `10` and also the `minCount` logic looks right, but I'd print that out to make sure you're getting what you expect.

```
if indexPath.row == currentResultsTitleArray.count - 4 && indexPath.row > self.highestIndexFetchedOn {

    let minCount = min(resultsTitleArray.count, currentResultsTitleArray.count + rowPerPage as Int) - 1
    let next = self.currentResultsTitleArray.count

    print("Count:",minCount)

    self.currentResultsTitleArray += self.resultsTitleArray[next...minCount]

    // etc...

    self.highestIndexFetchedOn = indexPath.row
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I'm not sure about the data structure here with all these arrays housing the different data either... I think one array of dictionaries that have all the values in would be better and simplify what we're looking at.. but I can't say 100% without seeing the rest of the class..